# YOLOv4 loss too high

Tags: tensorflow, yolo

I am using YOLOv4-tiny for a custom dataset of 26 classes that I collected from [Open Images Dataset](https://storage.googleapis.com/openimages/web/visualizer/index.html?set=train&type=segmentation&r=false&c=%2Fm%2F01jfm_). The dataset is almost balanced(850 images per class but different number of bounding boxes). When I used YOLOv4-tiny to train on just 3 classes the loss was near 0.5, it was fairly accurate. But for 26 classes as soon as the loss goes below 2 the model starts to overfit. The prediction are also very inaccurate.

I have tried to change the parameters like the learning rate, the momentum and the size but whatever I do the models becomes worse then before. Using regular YOLOv4 model rather then YOLO-tiny does not help either. How can I bring the loss further down?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried [training with mAP](https://github.com/AlexeyAB/darknet#how-to-train-to-detect-your-custom-objects)? You can take a subset of your training set and make it the validation set. This can be done in the same way you made your training and test set. Then, you can run `darknet.exe detector train data/obj.data yolo-obj.cfg yolov4.conv.137 -map`. This will keep track of the loss in your validation set. When the error in the validation say goes up, this is the time to stop training and prevent overfitting (this is called: early stopping).

Answer (score 0):

You need to run the training for (**classes*2000**)iterations. However, for the best scores, you need to train your model for at least 6000 iterations (also known as `max_batches`). Also please remember if you are using a b&w image, change the `channels=3` to `channels=1`. You can stop your training once the avg loss becomes something like this: `0.XXXX`.

Here's my mAP graph for 6000 iterations that ran for 6.2 hours:
[avg loss with 6000 max_batches](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VdiTl.png).

Moreover, you can follow this FAQ documentation [here](https://www.ccoderun.ca/programming/darknet_faq/) by Stéphane Charette.